# Replacing certain commands with parenthesis/brackets while keeping the content (CLI)

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I have a `plain text` file with `LaTeX` commands like `\hspace{5cm}`. To convert this file to `.odt` some of my custom commands are not converted correctly. So I want to automatically find & replace *specific* commands but keep the content of the brackets (meaning that I want to keep most of the commands and just delete some). I know that I can just open `gedit` and do the replacing by hand, but this is for a script for repeated, automatic replacement.

I already searched for this, but so far only found answers to delete brackets while keeping there content (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522855/how-to-remove-square-brackets-and-any-text-inside), here)). I also looked at some introductions to `sed` (e.g. [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/local/docs/An_introduction_to_sed.html#subsav)  or [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4)) without any success.

#### Example:

`This is my \textbf{text} where there are about \prc{5} commands, i.e. \mErrRange{30}{20}{m}.`

So, since these are a percentage and an error range, I want to delete the command & curly brackets and get something like this (keeping the `\textbf{...}` command):

`This is my \textbf{text} where there are 5 % commands, i.e. 30 ± 20 m.`

**What I tried so far:**

Various ways to use`sed`, like:

`sed -i -e 's/\\prc{\(.*\)}/\1%/g' hello.txt`

This already gives me:

`This is my \textbf{text} where there are about 5} commands, i.e. \mErrRange{30}{20}{m%.`

*(Replacing the last curly bracket in the line, but leaving the other one in its place.)*

So, now I have no clue how to continue with that. Maybe I should use another tool instead of `sed`?! I am happy about any suggestion running on Ubuntu & in the `terminal` without installing too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```bsh
sed 's/\\prc{\([^}]*\)}/\1 %/g'
```

This will capture everything inside the brackets following `\prc` and save it in group `1`, you can use this to replace the command with the content of the brackets. `[^}]*` simply takes everything except the closing bracket here. `g` stands for “globally” and means it will substitute all occurences of the pattern in the line instead of just the first one – you'll want that for every expression in your case.

As for the other one, just use multiple groups:

```bsh
sed 's/\\mErrRange{\([^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}/\1 ± \2 \3/g'
```

You can combine as many of those expressions as you like, but it gets easily unclear. I recommend writing a `sed` script with one expression per line like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/sed -f
s/\\prc{\([^}]*\)}/\1 %/g
s/\\mErrRange{\([^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}/\1 ± \2 \3/g
```

Save it as e.g. `script.sed`, make it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/script.sed` and run it with `/path/to/script.sed`.

#### Example run

```
$ /path/to/script.sed <hello.txt
This is my \textbf{text} where there are about 5 % commands, i.e. 30 ± 20 m.
```

<sub>I let the shell open input files as often as possible, hence `<hello.txt` instead of just `hello.txt` (which also works!). If you're interested in what ups this exactly has I recommend [this answer on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70759).</sub>

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I was searching for the `[^}]*` part. It is imho hard to find good documentation on `sed`.

Comment: Oh, just saw that you forgot to escape the `\prc` & `\mErrRange` in the script part (but couldn't edit it since these are not > 6 char.)
And thanks for the extra explanation on why to use `<hello.txt` here :)

Comment: @bamphe You're totally right, I corrected it – thank you! As for regular expressions, I really like [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), `sed` uses [POSIX BRE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) and what you searched for are [POSIX Bracket Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). To try it out I often use https://regexr.com.

Comment: Nice! These are really helpful sites, thanks again :)